# in_array doesn`t select multiple values of checkbox collected from DB

Tags: php

When database query  has many values [Permanent ID,Trainee ID Card,ID Card] it doesn't get checked for unknown reason

Below QUERY  to get the checkbox 
cardtype has all the the checked values from the form

It works fine only for one checkbox field 
1) Permanent ID Card or Trainee ID Card or ID Card
2) When Permanent ID Card ,Trainee ID Card , ID Card only checkbox is shown its not checked.

```
while($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
{
    $card_type = explode(',',$row2['cardtype']);
    if (in_array("Permanent ID Card", $card_type))  
    {  
    echo "'Permanent ID Card' found in the array";  
    }  
    <input type="checkbox" name="cardtype" value="Trainee ID Card"<?php if(in_array("Trainee ID Card",$card_type)) echo "checked";?> />Trainee ID Card
    <input type="checkbox" name="cardtype" value="Permanent ID Card"<?php if(in_array("Permanent ID Card",$card_type))  echo "checked";?> />Permanent ID Card
    <input type="checkbox" name="cardtype" value=" ID Card"<?php if(in_array(" ID Card",$card_type))  echo "checked";?> /> ID Card
 }
```

when I print-r

> Array ( [0] => Trainee ID Card [1] => Permament ID Card [2] => ID Card ) as output

Comment: You should print your `$card_type` and see what you're getting: `echo '<pre>'; print_r($card_type)`

Comment: Can you inspect element the HTML generated for that checkbox? I suspect that there's no space after the  value="Trainee ID Card".

Comment: @JeffreyHitosis there's space

Comment: Permament ID Card != Permanent ID Card that's y in_array is false

Comment: @BunkerBoy I have made changes thanks But ID card doesn't get selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ensure there's no space in the if conditions. Also, after applying `explode`, trim the whitespaces

```
$card_type = explode(',',$row2['cardtype']);

$card_type = array_map('trim', $card_type); // Add this line
```

HTML code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cardtype" value="Trainee ID Card"<?php if(in_array("Trainee ID Card",$card_type)) echo "checked";?> />Trainee ID Card
<input type="checkbox" name="cardtype" value="Permanent ID Card"<?php if(in_array("Permanent ID Card",$card_type))  echo "checked";?> />Permanent ID Card
<input type="checkbox" name="cardtype" value=" ID Card"<?php if(in_array("ID Card",$card_type))  echo "checked";?> /> ID Card
```